# laravel10-livewire- undefined variable

Tags: laravel-livewire

hello I start in laravel and I also start with livewire. I encounter the error "undefined variable" in the "index" view even though it is declared at the level of the "Index" class here are the different codes below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I recommerce several times with the instrctions of the documentation without difference. https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/quickstart

I don't know where I made a mistake. Please help

Comment: Hello at stack**overflow**. Please include what's essential to your question in the question body - hyperlinks welcome for reference & detail. Time allowing, (re)visit [How do I ask a Good Question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Never post screenshots for questions. Post your code instead. This makes it easier to follow as well as reproduce for anyone who might want to help. Anyway, did you include `@livewireScripts` and `@livewireStyles`?